# What is wfd-invisible="true" attribute?

Tags: html

I'm creating a website and sometimes I keep seeing this attribute `wfd-invisible="true"` in my elements that set as `display:none;`, even though I don't specifically assigned it.

I googled it, there is almost no information about it. I did find `wfd-id` attribute that they says it related to kaspersky password manager. I'm using kaspersky as my antivirus, is this the one causing to assign `wfd-invisible="true"` in my hidden elements?

I'm using firefox version 96.0, it mostly appeared on hidden elements e.g. `<script>` or elements with `display:none;`, extensions I use are block site, enchancer for youtube, I dont care about cookies, Take webpage screebshots and ublock origin. I using python as backend programming language and framework I'm using is flask

Comment: I'm assuming your sources don't contain it, so where does it appear and when? Which browser (make + version) are you using? Which (possibly shady) extensions have been installed in the browser? How is your website hosted? How do you create, build and deploy the website? Please [edit] the question and provide as much detail as possible, including source code and browser screenshots.

Comment: Well, if you already found out that Kaspersky is related and you have Kaspersky installed, then yes, it's probably it. Likely a browser extension.

Comment: See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/333231/a-weird-attribute-on-every-html-tag

Comment: Yeah that could be it, I just find it weird that there is almost no information about this attribute. I probably ask directly Kaspersky support about this

Answer (score 3):

I had the same behavior and it was caused by Kaspersky Internet Security:
when KIS is enabled with the "Inject script into web traffic" option, the wfd-invisible attribute is injected into web pages.

In Chrome normal mode :
the attribute is injected only when KIS protection is enabled (not paused) and the option "Inject script into web traffic" is enabled.

In Chrome incognito mode :
the attribute is never injected, whether KIS protection is enabled or not

Tested with KIS 21.3.10 and Chrome 104

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and found that Ad-Blocker was the culprit for me.

This affected text input fields and textareas in my case.

For reasons unknown (for which I am still trying to determine) if the element was contained in a div/pane/etc. that was originally hidden, when the parent element was shown, text fields and textareas remained hidden with the wfd-invisible="true" element.

Disabling Ad-Blocker for the page reactivated the missing elements.